# Enable special characters in directory name?

Tags: texlive, sublime-text, sumatrapdf

I'm using Sublime Text 2 + TeXlive + SumatraPDF (in a win8 PC) to write my documents. I've noticed that, if my directory name doesn't contain special characters, such as `é` or `ã` or `ç`, Sublime compiles and automatically launches SumatraPDF with the resulting PDF. However, if I do have a special character, it doesn't launch SumatraPDF, although it compiles correctly and generates the PDF (but I have to open the file manually).

Is there anyway to enable special characters so that SumatraPDF is launched as soon as the PDF is generated?

Thanks in advance,

Bernardo

Comment: Try a new binary of the SumatraPDF
`http://www.math.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/~abenori/tmp/SumatraPDF.zip`
which my friend built by using the `synctex_parser_utils.c` in the
present TeX Live repository.

Comment: Should I just download unzip the file content in the SumatraPDF directory? If so, it hasn't solved the problem

Comment: I misunderstood the issue, sorry. Your problem is
in the editor `Sublime Text 2`.
In the new binary of SumatraPDF, very special
characters in file names, such as `Kanji` in
japanese windows, can be used in SyncTeX without
any problem. The issue solved by the new binary
is not your present concern.